# How we can ignore writing file contents in RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware AspNetcore3

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.0, .net-core-3.1

Is this correct way when I don't want to log the file data using the given condition, that the contentType is application/json or any other way is there to skip writing the file contents?

```
if (context.Response.ContentType.Contains("application/json"))
{
logger(responseBody);
}

if (!context.Request.ContentType.Contains("application/json"))
{
logger(requestBody);
}
```

Comment: It is just based on your needs when to do the log or not. There is no problem just from the codes.

Comment: the middleware is handling the request and responses in my code and is printing all responses and requests in the console. I would like to exclude the response and request if the type is file